# Syntax explanation (dot syntax)

Tags: objective-c

In my app i have following line of code:

```
self.nameLabel.text = searchResult.name;
```

I wonder, how could i write it without dots? That is how i tried to do this:

```
[[self nameLabel] text] = [searchResult name];
```

or

```
[[self nameLabel] text] = searchResult.name;
```

Look right for me, i calling getter methods of properties, but Xcode warn me with fatal error - Expression is not assignable.

But `[[self nameLabel] text]` produce same variable `text` as `self.nameLabel.text`, just like `searchResult.name` is equal to `[searchResult name]`.

Why is that happen?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: try `[[self nameLabel]setText:@"Test"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[self nameLabel] text]` returns you a text value, and it is not assignable.
Use `[[self nameLabel] setText: [searchResult name]]` setter method.